# hibernate order by count joined table and return list of pojos

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate, left-join

suppose i have OneEntity that contains set of AnotherEntity

```
@Entity
public class OneEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<AnotherEntity> anotherEntities;

}
```

For now i have for about 30000 rows in OneEntity and for about 500000 rows in AnotherEntity, some OneEntities have 10-100 AnotherEntityes, but some of them have 1000 and more (this is important)

and now i want get first 20 OneEntities with biggest AnotherEntities count (but without AnotherEntities data, set will be empty same as if i use lazy collection) as fast as possible.

Hibernate creates 3 tables: OneEntity, OneEntity_AnotherEntity, AnotherEntity.

When i process query in mysql console

```
SELECT *, COUNT(anotherEntityId) as anotherEntityCount from OneEntity left join OneEntity_AnotherEntity on OneEntity.oneEntityId = OneEntity_AnotherEntity.oneEntityId group by OneEntity.oneEntityId order by anotherEntityCount desc limit 0,20;
```

is takes me for about **0.3 sec** and as a result i have (for example) next table with next fields:

- oneEntityId;
- oneEntityName;
- oneEntityDescription;
- anotherEntityCount;

now i want to perform this using hibernate, i googled such solution:

```
criteria.createAlias("anotherEntities", "anotherEntity");
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("oneEnityId")).add(Projections.count("anotherEntity.anotherEntityId"), "anotherEntityCount"));
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("anotherEntityCount"));
```

but in this case i obtain next array:

```
[
  [
    427636,
    52268
  ],
  [
    645779,
    47529
  ],
  and so on...
]
```

and it takes me **13!!!** seconds (against 0.3 seconds in mysql console)

question - how i can query OneEntity ordered by AnotherEntity count and obtain list of OneEntities (which won't contain set of anotherEntities) less than in 13 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I guess can use hql query, something like this:

```
EntityManager em = ....
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT new HashMap<e,COUNT(e.id)> FROM OneEntity e ... GROUP BY e.id");
q.getResultList();
```

It will return a list of Map. Hope it works for you.

Comment: i'm using hibernate criteria because there may be up to 7 parameters in query (such as name, description, some boolean values, etc) for query. yes, sure, i can manually build query (and may produce bugs, sql injections, etc) but may be there are solution using criteria?